# Hiding a TextView contained in a subclass of Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

As of now: When the user enters the settings page there's a single option that is prefixed with "New". When the user clicks this option nothing happens.

Objective: When the user enters the settings page and clicks on the option prefixed with "New" the "New" prefix's visibility should be set to View.GONE.

**Assume all layouts and their references are set and accessed correctly to shorten code snippets**

MyCustomPreference.kt

```
class MyCustomPreference @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    val attr: AttributeSet? = null,
    private val defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : Preference(context, attr, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        layoutResource = R.layout.my_layout
    }

    var showNewLabel = false

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
        with(holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view_new)) {
            visibility = if (showNewLabel) {
                View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

setupPreferences.kt

```
// Assume everything works (ex: onViewCreated, onCreate)
open class PreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        setupPreference()
    }

private fun setupPreference() {
        findPreference<MyCustomPreference>(getText(R.string.my_custom_pref_key))?.apply {
            showNewLabel = true // correctly displays (or hides if set to false) TextView
            setOnPreferenceClickListener {


             // *ISSUE* this does not update UI to hide TextView. 
             // My CustomPreference's onBindViewHolder is not called again and 
             // if I try to grab the reference to the TextView manually its value is null
                showNewLabel = false

             // return true or false doesn't matter here
                true 
            }
        }
    }


}
```

When setupPreference's onClickListener is called nothing to the UI changes. The only time MyCustomPreference is re-rendered is when the user exists and re-enters the settings menu. Is there a way to force render the CustomPreference knowing that its data has changed (showNewLabel)?

Thank you!

Comment: Just make your own preference screen. It's one of the simplest screens in any app. I can't tell you how many questions on here are from people trying to work around the limitations of the built-in preference screen.

Comment: Is this not using its own preference screen? I don't believe you read my post as this is in its own preference screen and is being rendered (prior to user interaction) as expected. @GavinWright

Comment: You're extending `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. I'm recommending that you extend `Fragment` instead.

Comment: I'm a junior dev learning Android for the first time and working with someone else’s work. I'm not sure if it's possible for me to change the classes we are inheriting from. Would you be able to supply a code snippet better explaining why inheriting from Fragment would be better for this use case? Now that I think of it, `PreferenceFragmentCompat` does extend `Fragment` but without extending to `PreferenceFragmentCompat` specifically I will be unable to access my Preferences entirely @GavinWright

Comment: What kind of UI elements are showing on the preference screen? `Switch`es, `Spinner`s, `RadioButton`s? These are all just simple `View`s that you can add in your own layout. Then, [you can access and save the values of `SharedPreferences` quite easily](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). If you have a `Switch`, for instance, you can save its value in an [`OnCheckedChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener).

Comment: Everything will be backwards-compatible with the current implementation as long as you maintain the same names for your `SharedPreferences` keys.

Comment: To keep things simple, I'm showing a single TextView but our preferences contain complex styles hence we have custom preference classes that extend `Preference` in order to render these complex XML layouts and to refer to them programmatically in our fragment that does the setup such as attaching onClickListeners to specific preferences and such. I just want to be able to modify the data inside one of these custom preference classes and see the results instantly on the settings screen without having to close and re-open it. As of now, the preference does not re-render @GavinWright as it should

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding when you consider what I am trying to achieve  and the feedback you're providing. While it's good feedback I believe you're solving a different problem, a problem that I have already solved. This is not a matter of creating and using custom preferences. It's a matter of updating a custom preference's `data` (showNewLabel) and seeing it being re-rendered (hidden) when I click on the preference's onClickListener. The onClickListener is working correctly as it performs other logic not included in the snippet but it doesn’t hide the TextView @GavinWright

Comment: I don't believe that `PreferenceFragmentCompat` is intended for customizations like this. Which is why everyone who wants to do something more involved has moved away from them.